# How to create global style for Xamarin forms application

Tags: xaml, styles, xamarin.forms

I am creating my first xamarin forms application using PCL on Mac machine with Xamarin Studio. 
I read so many articles to create a global style for application but I am not able to access style which declared in App.xaml.cs file any files inside the application. I mention below bit of code I used. Or if someone have other option to make it easy or anyhow possible please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

App.xaml.cs-

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="DinePerfect.App">
     <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style  x:Key="btnStyle"  TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Lime" />
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Teal" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Calling style in other file-

```
<Button Text="Login" Style="{StaticResource btnStyle} TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="#9C661F"  Clicked="btnLoginClicked" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like while converting your App class to XAML-based you've missed `InitializeComponent();` call in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to add InitializeComponent(); in your App.cs .When you have a xaml code you have to call InitializeComponent(); in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to set the BackgroundColor in the Style aswell to make the BorderColor work.

[From the Button.BorderColor Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderColor/)

> This property has no effect if Button.BorderWidth is set to 0. On Android this property will not have an effect unless VisualElement.BackgroundColor is set to a non-default color.

Style:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style  x:Key="btnStyle"  TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Lime" />
    <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Teal" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Usage in Xaml:

```
  <Button Text="Login" Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" />
```

This Works for me.

Edit: 
[Example Project](https://github.com/MJunak/ButtonStyleTest)

Comment: Hi @Marius -I don't know but I am struggling with it from two days and I am getting error that StaticResource btnStyle does not found. I am getting it if I am declaring above style inside every individual file. Can you please tell me what procedure you followed?

Comment: Hi, i added a link to the project where i reproduced your issue. Can you post a full xaml page where you are referencing the style? Im not sure why this is not working for you.